# Random voice in IE instructing me how to clear browser cache and cookies

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Browser IE 9
Platform: Windows 7 (64)

I think I have some sort of audio virus. As I am browsing, I occasionally get a voice that instructs me on how to clear the browser cache and cookies. I have check the “Ease of Access Center” section to ensure Windows Narrator is not on.

The voice sounds like it has an echo or like its running twice a fraction of a second from the first audio.

Actions Taken:

Ensure Windows Narrator off

Run Emisoft Malware Guard

Run Norton Anti Virus

Run Microsoft Malware scan

Attempted to locate a recent wave or audio file added to the system

Comment: Have you tried firefox or chrome ?

Answer (score 3):

One explanation could be that you have a malfunctioning or malicious add-on in IE9.

You can see if this is the problem by going to the Start menu and clicking Run, type `iexplore -extoff` and then click OK. This will launch IE in "Safe mode" (no extensions). If the problem doesn't occur any more, then it’s probably caused by an add-on, and you will need to disable the offending add-on.

To do that, go to `Tools–>Manage Add-ons` (enable the Menu Bar if necessary) and scroll through them. The Microsoft ones are usually ok. Look for anything that is marked corrupt or doesn’t have publisher information and disable it. Close IE completely and try to open it normally. Repeat this process, disabling add-ons until you hit on the one that is giving you trouble. If you think you still need that add-on then goto the publisher’s website and look for an updated version.

If the problem occurs also in IE Safe mode, I suggest that you also try the following antivirus products: [Malwarebytes](https://malwarebytes.org/) and [SUPERAntiSpyware](https://www.superantispyware.com/).

It might also be an adware infection that is not caught by an antivirus. The following are good anti-adware products: [Spybot-S&D!](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html) and [Lavasoft](http://www.lavasoft.com/).

Ensure in all cases that the virus definitions are updated before running a scan. Take backups and ensure you can re-install Windows and all your products, as eradicating an infection can render your computer unbootable.

Actually, the normal advice when an infection is found, is actually to format the hard drive and reinstall everything, but we don't know yet if your computer is really infected or this is some kind of a malfunction.

Comment: Does Google Toolbar count as "a malfunctioning or malicious add-on"? My vote is yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Google Toolbar installed, go to *Tools > Internet Options > Programs > Manage add-ons > Toolbars and Extensions* and disable the Google Toolbar Helper. You don't have to uninstall the toolbar, just disable the toolbar helper.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the voice you are hearing?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKTPncO-0_g

[Uninstall Google Toolbar.](http://www.google.com/support/toolbar/bin/answer.py?answer=9231)

Comment: Video link now dead.